# Hexagon Area Question

Tags: geometry

Triangle ABC has AB = 15, BC = 13, and AC = 14. Let O be the orthocenter of this triangle, and let the reflections from the orthocenter across sides AB, BC, and AC be points D, E, and F, respectively. Find the area of ADBECF.

I was able to show that this hexagon was concyclic, but I don't know the best way to proceed from there.

[image: Hexagon]

Comment: By the reflection construction, $\triangle AOB \cong \triangle ADB$ etc. The areas of $\triangle AOB, \triangle BOC, \triangle COA$ together is the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @peterwhy so it will be 2(84) = 168?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I would recommend drawing this out and posting a picture.

Answer (score 3):

The area is double the area of the initial triangle. The triangle is divided into 3 sections and reflecting each of those sections outside the triangle creates a shape with twice the area. The area of the initial triangle can be calculated using just the known side lengths of the triangle and [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

$$a = 2\sqrt{p(p-13)(p-14)(p-15)} = 168$$ where the semi-perimeter $p = (13+14+15)/2$